# SQL query to add points from two tables within a database

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, union

I'm about to have a cow here. I'm designing a hockey pool database, which at the moment consists of 3 tables as follows:

```
Table 1                 Table 2                   Table 3
TeamID   TeamName       GoalieID TeamID Points    SkaterID TeamID Points
1        Marlies        1        1      10        1        4      20
2        Colts          2        3      5         2        1      25
3        Sting          3        2      6         3        3      7
4        Steelheads     4        4      7         4        2      12
```

The actual tables have a lot more players and teams, this is just an example.
I'm looking to create a query that will combine points totals for each player from Table2 and Table3, and display this information right next to the Team Name.

```
Team Name      Total Points
Steelheads     27
Marlies        25 
Colts          18
Sting          12
```

I have no problems summing points from a single table but unfortunately I'm having trouble wrapping my head around combining points that span across multiple tables. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: It's an MSAccess database.

Comment: ... after doing a bit of research last night I realized the query from mcNets was missing parentheses around the nested JOIN. That fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Do a `UNION ALL` in a derived table (`p`) to get all players at once, including goalies. `LEFT JOIN` with that result to get all teams with players' points. Finally do a `GROUP BY` and sum the points.

```
SELECT t1.TeamName, sum(p.Points) as TotalPoints
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN (select TeamID, Points from Table2
           union all
           select TeamID, Points from Table3) p
        ON t1.TeamId = p.TeamId
GROUP BY t1.TeamName
```

(Have you considered to have all players in the same table?)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will give this a whirl and see what happens. I did manage to get mcNets suggestion going but the numbers are way out of whack and I think I know what's causing it. I did consider having one table for all but the Goalies table has extra fields that the Skaters does not.. this would cause the Skaters table to have too many empty fields....in the end I just might have to go that way. Thanks again.

Comment: It worked!!!! I added a couple of WHERE conditionals to the query and it's giving me what I'm looking for. I must say I did try UNIONs and subqueries yesterday but none worked for me - probably because I was getting really tired and cranky... but this is awesome. Thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    Table1.TeamName,
    sum(isNull(Table2.Points,0) + isNull(Table3.Points,0)) as TotalPoints
FROM
    Table1
    LEFT JOIN Table2
        ON Table1.TeamId = Table2.TeamId
    LEFT JOIN Table3
        ON Table1.TeamId = Table3.TeamId
GROUP BY
   Table1.TeamName
```

Comment: Thanks... unfortunately it throws an error - Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'PoolTeams.ID = MondaySkaterStats.PoolTeam LEFT JOIN MondayGoalieStats ON PoolTeams.ID = MondayGoalieStats.PoolTeam'

Comment: ----- let me play with this for a while and see if I can fix it. Thanks for steering me in the right direction.

Comment: Note that NULL + value = NULL.

Comment: One of the things I failed to mention was that I was using an MSAccess database. I had no idea it required parentheses around nested JOINs. It seems to have fixed the query but gave me weird numbers and after thinking about it a bit I know why. Anyway, all is good now. Thanks again.

Comment: I assumed MySql

Comment: No worries... I appreciate the help. It allowed me to gain some understanding of JOINs as up until now it was way over my head.